# Amcharts 5 XY Chart change "y axis label color", "x label color" and "legend color" then add value over bars

Tags: amcharts, amcharts5

I have the following XY graph that I have created by using Amcharts 5. It has two series, one for (Kanban tasks) "Created" and one for  (Kanban tasks) "Closed".

[image]

I want to edit the following:

- y axis label color
- x label color
- legend color
- add value over bars

[image]

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
  <head>
    <title>Graph</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="tmp.css" />

                <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0" />
                </head>
<body>
<!-- Amcharts -->
    <script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/index.js"></script>

                <script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/xy.js"></script>
                <script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/themes/Animated.js"></script>
                <!-- //Amcharts -->
    <!-- Chart code :: graph_tasks_created_and_closed_per_month -->
    <script>
        am5.ready(function() {
            // Create root element
            // https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/getting-started/#Root_element
            var rootA = am5.Root.new("chartdiv_graph_tasks_created_and_closed_per_month");

            // Set themes
            // https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/concepts/themes/
            rootA.setThemes([
              am5themes_Animated.new(rootA)
            ]);



            // Create chart
            // https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/xy-chart/
            var chartA = rootA.container.children.push(am5xy.XYChart.new(rootA, {
              panX: false,
              panY: false,
              layout: rootA.verticalLayout
            }));

            // Add legend
            // https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/xy-chart/legend-xy-series/
            var legendA = chartA.children.push(
              am5.Legend.new(rootA, {
                centerX: am5.p50,
                x: am5.p50
              })
            );

            // Set data
            var data = [{
                  xlabelXYChart: "Jun",
                  value1: 48,
                  value2: 20
                }];
        // Create axes
        // https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/xy-chart/axes/
        var xAxis = chartA.xAxes.push(am5xy.CategoryAxis.new(rootA, {
          categoryField: "xlabelXYChart",
          renderer: am5xy.AxisRendererX.new(rootA, {
            cellStartLocation: 0.1,
            cellEndLocation: 0.9
          }),
          tooltip: am5.Tooltip.new(rootA, {})
        }));
        
        xAxis.data.setAll(data);
        
        var yAxis = chartA.yAxes.push(am5xy.ValueAxis.new(rootA, {
          renderer: am5xy.AxisRendererY.new(rootA, {})
        }));
        
        
        // Add series
        // https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/xy-chart/series/
        function makeSeries(name, fieldName) {
          var series = chartA.series.push(am5xy.ColumnSeries.new(rootA, {
            name: name,
            xAxis: xAxis,
            yAxis: yAxis,
            valueYField: fieldName,
            categoryXField: "xlabelXYChart"
          }));
        
          series.columns.template.setAll({
            tooltipText: "{categoryX} {name}: {valueY}",
            width: am5.percent(90),
            tooltipY: 0
          });
        
          series.data.setAll(data);
        
          // Make stuff animate on load
          // https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/concepts/animations/
          series.appear();
        
          series.bullets.push(function () {
            return am5.Bullet.new(rootA, {
              locationY: 0,
              sprite: am5.Label.new(rootA, {
                text: "{valueY}",
                fill: rootA.interfaceColors.get("alternativeText"),
                centerY: 0,
                centerX: am5.p50,
                populateText: true
              })
            });
          });
        
          legendA.data.push(series);
        }
        
        
        makeSeries("Created", "value1");
        makeSeries("Closed", "value2");

        }); // end am5.ready()
    </script>

    <div id="chartdiv_graph_tasks_created_and_closed_per_month" style="width: 100%;min-height: 150px;"></div>

    <!-- //Chart code :: tasks_created_and_closed_per_month -->
</body>
</html>
```

How can I edit the colors of the labels and show the value over the series?